# Worst case time complexity of edit distance?

Tags: time-complexity, edit-distance

I am trying to calculate the worst case scenario time complexity for finding the edit distance from `T` test words to `D` dictionary words, where all words have a length `MAX_LEN`.

Answer (score 1):

Worst time complexity can be exponential, `O(3^MAX_LEN)` when using a naive recursive solution. The worst-case happens when none of the characters of two strings match.

Comment: What if you are not using the recursive solution, but a bottom-up dynamic programming solution? Does that change the complexity?

Comment: @blurred42 Using a bottom-up DP solution reduces the time complexity to `O(MAX_LEN^2)` which is polynomial time but also increases space complexity to the same.